# How can I fix this css left alignment?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I made every option into a container, so I have 8 containers, from left to right, from top to bottom.

But for some unknown reason, item_container 3 and 4 are not following the alignment!! I've spent hours on this but no good. So frustrating right now.

[image]

Here is my html code. `item_container` 5~8 are basically the same as 1,2, and they aligned perfectly, so I didn't include them.

```css
.page_item {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 28px;
 margin-right: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.page_field {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 68px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.page_check_field {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.page_container {
 display: block;
 width: 876px;
 height: 74px;
}

.page_container .item_container1, .page_container .item_container2, .page_container .item_container3, .page_container .item_container4, .page_container .item_container5, .page_container .item_container6, .page_container .item_container7, .page_container .item_container8 {
 display: inline-block;
}

.item_container1, .item_container2, .item_container3 .item_container4, .item_container5, .item_container6, .item_container7, .item_container8 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 436px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_container">
   <div class="item_container1">
    <h6 class="page_item">User ID</h6>
    <div class="page_field form-group form-group-label">
     <label class="page_entry floating-label" for="..."> Entry User ID </label>
     <input class="form-control" id="..." type="text">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item_container2"> 
    <h6 class="page_item">Country</h6>
    <div class="page_field form-group form-group-label">
     <select class="page_entry form-control" id="...">
      <option value="..."> Select </option>
      <option value="..."> Country 1 </option>
      <option value="..."> Country 2 </option>
      <option value="..."> Country 3 </option>
      <option value="..."> Country 4 </option>
      <option value="..."> Country 5 </option>
      <option value="..."> Country that has very long name </option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="page_container">
   <div class="item_container3">
    <h6 class="page_item">Email</h6>
    <div class="page_field form-group form-group-label">
     <label class="floating-label" for="..."> Entry User Email </label>
     <input class="form-control" id="..." type="text">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item_container4">
    <h6 class="page_item">User Type</h6>
    <div class="page_check_field">
     <div class="checkbox checkbox-adv">
      <label for="check1">
      <input class="access-hide" id="check1" name="check1" type="checkbox">Cosplayer
      <span class="checkbox-circle"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-circle-check"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-circle-icon icon">done</span>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_check_field">
     <div class="checkbox checkbox-adv">
      <label for="check2">
      <input class="access-hide" id="check2" name="check2" type="checkbox">Cameraman
      <span class="checkbox-circle"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-circle-check"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-circle-icon icon">done</span>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_check_field">
     <div class="checkbox checkbox-adv">
      <label for="check3">
      <input class="access-hide" id="check3" name="check3" type="checkbox">Organizer
      <span class="checkbox-circle"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-circle-check"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-circle-icon icon">done</span>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It rather defeats the purpose of having classes when you give them unique identifiers...

Comment: In fact this is the cause of your problem. Your absurdly long selector includes `... , .item_container3 .item_container4, ...`, missing a `,` in there and causing the problem. Just make them all `class="item_container"`, dispense with the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a missing comma in this line that's probably causing your trouble

```
.item_container2, .item_container3 .item_container4,
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is .page-container don't width enough. 
.item_container4 too large over the .page-container width. 
To fix this simply you only need change width of .page-container larger .
Can be set width : 
.page-container {
    width: 920px;
    .........
}
It work correctly!
Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

```
.item_container1, .item_container2, .item_container3, .item_container4, .item_container5, .item_container6, .item_container7, .item_container8 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 436px;
}

, between item_container3 and item_container4 is missing and i thought you might be adjust your width for better look
```